# Python Paramiko Error

Tags: python, ssh

I wrote a python program. I have conf file, I wrote router configuration commands inside the conf file and I want to execute these commands inside paramiko. I have a problem - the error message is below. Can you help me please ?

## CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko
ip="10.100.1.200"
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,username="admin",password="pass")

text=open("conf")

for komut in text.readlines():

        stdin, stdout, stderror = ssh.exec_command(komut)
        for line in stdout.readlines():
                        print line.strip()


ssh.close()

text.close()
```

## error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configmaker.py", line 13, in <module>
    stdin, stdout, stderror = ssh.exec_command(str(komut.strip()))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 370, in exec_command
    chan = self._transport.open_session()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 662, in open_session
    return self.open_channel('session')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 764, in open_channel
    raise e
EOFError
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code:

```
import paramiko

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = "127.0.0.1"
    username = "admin"
    password = "root"

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip,username=username,password=password)
    ssh_transport = ssh.get_transport()

    for command in ("ls /tmp", "date"):
        chan = ssh_transport.open_session()
        chan.exec_command(command)
        exit_code = chan.recv_exit_status()
        stdin = chan.makefile('wb', -1)         # pylint: disable-msg=W0612
        stdout = chan.makefile('rb', -1)
        stderr = chan.makefile_stderr('rb', -1)  # pylint: disable-msg=W0612
        output = stdout.read()
        print output
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, first copy the conf file to remote server and execute the file.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
host = str(host)
user = 'root'
pw = 'root123'
ssh.connect(host, username=user, password=pw)

filepath = "conf"
remote_path = "/root/qats_tool.tar"

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put(filepath, remote_path)

command="./conf"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
sftp.close()
```